# How to use trunk, branches, tags in svn from eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, svn, tortoisesvn, subversive

Here is what i want to know.

We will develop a software and releases a major version v1.0 of it.

After moving that version into production if we find any bugs we will fix those and deliver a patch version p1.0.1 to be applied over the existing major versionv1.0 which consists only modified classes for the bug fix. And it continues like whenever any bug found or an enhancement has to be applied, we will release a new patch version to be applied over the existing major version and existing patches.

So, How can we maintain only modified source(java) files for particular patch release? Like we need to have complete source code and separately we have to maintain patch source on top of that. We have to sync this code in SVN as multiple people involve in bug fixing, and patching.

Trunk, Branches, Tags will it full-fill our needs?

Please suggest.

Comment: Your main development is on the Subversion trunk.  When you're ready to release version 1.0, you tag the trunk.  If you need to apply any bug fixes, you work from the tag.  You create a new tag for version 1.0.1 when the bug fix work is complete.  Meanwhile, version 1.1 is developed on the trunk.

Comment: @ Gilbert Le Blanc Thanks for your quick reply. When I create a tag it is copying all source files from trunk to tag. To fix the bug we will have to find the appropriate class and modify it. Then we cant release a newer version using entire source code from tag but only one class we will include in the newer version which we have modified. Every time we are manually identifying the modified classes and releasing a newer version.

Comment: No, Subversion does not copy all the source files from the tag to the trunk.  Subversion creates pointers.  Your bug fixers check out the release tag, while your developers continue on the trunk.  You don't have to manually identify any classes.  Subversion identifies the conflicts for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several standard ways of doing development. I like what's called the *unstable trunk* method.

In unstable trunk, you do all of your development on trunk. Everyone works together. We have over 100 developers and don't have issues with it. It forces developers to work together, make small changes, and constantly commit these changes.

It also works well with a continuous integration builder like [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org).

When you get to some *magic point*, you create a *release branch*. What is this *magic point*? It depends. The idea is that as you get close to a release, you will have some developers working on the up coming release and some developers working on features that will go into the very next release. Two groups working in parallel means branching.

In some groups, this is when you get to the point of a release candidate or when you are feature complete on a release, and now you're just fixing bugs. At that point, you create a branch for your release. Our standard is to call that branch after your release.

### Example: Creating a release

You have a team of 10 developers. You are working on Release 1.2. All work is currently on trunk. Now that the release is almost complete, you assign two of those developers to work with QA and UAT to fix up the code and work on the release. All other developers are continue their work.

You create a branch called `1.2` using `svn cp` to copy `trunk` to `branches/1.2`. Now, those two developers working with QA and UAT work on Branch 1.2 and the rest continue working on trunk.

Once you are ready to release the code, you can use `svn cp` to copy `branches/1.2` to `tags/1.2`.

You now have some bugs that have been fixed on your 1.2 release that may apply to that 1.3 release you're working on in `trunk`. In that case, you can use `svn merge -c $REV` where `$REV` is the revision in Subversion where you fixed the pertinent bug. Notice there's no reintegration. You simply apply the patches in `branches/1.2` to `trunk`.

### Example: Patch Release

You've released Release 1.2, and a critical bug was discovered. The customers can't wait for Release 1.3, so you'll fix the bug now and create a Release 1.2.1.

In this case, since you already have `branches/1.2`, you simply patch that branch, and then when you are ready to do your release, you copy the `1.2` branch to `tags/1.2.1`.

Once again, you merge individual changes from `branches/1.2` to trunk via `svn merge -c $REV`.

> **NOTE**: There's no need to create a 1.2.1 branch. However, there's not anything preventing you to do that if you so prefer. You could have copies `tags/1.2` to `branches/1.2.1` and do your work there. Then, you could copy `branches/1.2.1` to `tags/1.2.1` when you do a release.
>
> The only possible issue is that your branching is from `trunk`->`branches/1.2`->`tags/1.2`->`branches/1.2.1`. Merging `/branches/1.2.1` back into `trunk` use to cause problems in older versions of Subversion. This shouldn't realy be an issue in Subversion 1.6 or greater.

One more piece of advice: Do not reuse release names or tags. You can talk about release 1.2, but each patch should be tagged 1.2.1, 1.2.2, 1.2.3, etc. Or, 1.2p1, 1.2p2. The point is that you should be able to point to each and every release you've delivered to production. If you want to know what changed in patch #3, you can do a diff between 1.2.2 and 1.2.3.

Comment: Thanks David . You are explanation clarified most of my doubts. As I am very new to use svn trunk, branches, tags, I am trying to do a practical example on what you have explained for my clear understanding.